# If does not work in bash

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/home/admin/test/temp/*

for f in $FILES
do
        echo "Working on: $f"
        query=$(cat $f)
        /usr/bin/mysql -h $1  -u admin -pwpasswd -e "$query"
        echo "$?"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ];
        then
        echo "Successfully uploaded. Deleting file $f"
        rm $f
        else
        echo "breaking..."
        break
        fi
done
```

the output:

> Working on: /home/admin/test/temp/temp_2014-08-01_02-40.txt ERROR 2003
>   (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.103' (110) 1
>   Successfully uploaded. Deleting file
>   /home/admin/test/temp/temp_2014-08-01_02-40.txt

According to the $? value which is 1, it should break the loop, but it does not.

Can somebody tell me what is the problem with it?

Comment: To the person who voted to close this: How is it not about programming?

Comment: @KeithThompson that's ironic. I could've sworn I chose *a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.*

Comment: @kojiro: You did; that's in the sub-menu after you selected "off-topic". The UI could be better.

Comment: The use of `echo "$?"` changes the value of `$?` as echo works just fine and have exit status 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$?` you're testing is the status of the `echo` command on the previous line.

If you want to echo it and then test it, save it in a variable:

```
/usr/bin/mysql ...
status=$?
echo "$status"
if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`$?` gets reset to the exit status of the most recent command. If that command is `echo $?`, the *next* `$?` will most assuredly be 0, or success.

Answer (score 0):

The "$?" variable represents the return status of the previous command executed. After the "/usr/bin/mysql .." line this is 1, as correctly observed from the output, since the query fails. But after executing the "echo $?" command, $? changes and now represents the return value of the "echo" command, which is 0, therefore incorrectly moving towards the "successfully uploaded" branch. Removing the echo line will most likely nudge your program towards the intended functionality.